# Get all file versions from s3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have uploaded few files (with the same name) in to s3 and it is now appears in object versions:
[image]

How I can get all file versions and delete them (left just latest)?
Method:

```
s3Bucket
.getObject({ Bucket, Key })
```

just returns last object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can get all versions of an object by [`s3.listObjectVersions`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjectVersions-property) method.

```
var params = {
  Bucket: "examplebucket", 
  Prefix: "HappyFace.jpg"
 };
 s3.listObjectVersions(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);  
});
```

- You can delete a specific version by passing `VersionId: 'STRING_VALUE'` to  [`s3.deleteObject`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#deleteObject-property) method.

```
var params = {
  Bucket: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  Key: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  VersionId: 'STRING_VALUE'
};
s3.deleteObject(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Comment: yes, but I need to extract list of all versions. Some files can have few versions, which id's I don't know.

Comment: @Ted you updated the question, I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

To get the list of all object versions, you can use [object_versions](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.object_versions):

```
import boto3

s3r = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket = s3r.Bucket('<your-bucket>')

for obj in bucket.object_versions.filter(Prefix='<your-key>'):  
  if not obj.is_latest:
    print("old", obj)
  else:
    print("last obj", obj)
```

`obj` is an instance of [ObjectVersion](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#objectversion) which has `delete` method.